# IIS Response.Redirect not resolving properly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

Are there any settings in IIS that could potentially affect Response.Redirect?

The user is on the page: "https://originaldomain/pages/map"  I am currently doing this:

```
Response.Redirect(url, true);
```

Where the URL variable is set to https://someotherdomainotherthanmine/I/am/Url.

Rather than resolving to https://someotherdomainotherthanmine/I/am/Url, it is resolving to https://originaldomain/I/am/Url.

What could be causing this change?

I'm currently moving a web application that is hosted on an on-premise server, to a VM hosted in AWS.  My application is working on the legacy hardware - ie the code hasn't changed between the code being self-hosted, and the code I'm using for the AWS instance.  This leads me to believe that this is some sort of setting in IIS, rather than something in the code.

Comment: That generates a 302 redirect response, have you looked in the browsers network tab to see the raw content of the Redirect response?  What is it?

Comment: When you look at the response (that redirects) in dev tools (F12), does the redirect header specify originaldomain, someotherdomain, or is it relative?

Comment: Outbound URL Rewrites?

Answer (score 0):

In the end, this was caused by the Application Requesting Routing Cache configuration at the server level of IIS.

The request was going from siteA.domain.com/path, rewritten to siteB.domain.com/path.  On the way out, siteA.domain.com was rewriting the host in the headers.

I had a checkbox checked "Reverse rewrite host in response headers" in ARR->Server Proxy Settings.

To find this settings, go to the server level node in IIS, open up Application Request Routing Cache.  On the right actions pane, under proxy there is an option "Server Proxy Settings".  Click it.  About four or so settings from the top, there is a checkbox "Reverse rewrite host in response headers".  For me, this was checked and was causing the headers to rewrite the host on the way out.  Unchecking it resolved my issue.